# Unit testing an object with argument captor before it is destroyed

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a method that returns void, it creates a `File` within and then passes this `file` object to another method. At the end, it will delete the `file`. I want to create a unit test to test the `file` content by using an argument captor on the other method that accepts the `file`. This works as I can get a hold onto the `file` object. However, by the time I can do some assertions, the `file` has already been deleted by the method, so even though I have the `file` object, I can't verify its content is correct or not. How do you write a unit test to test the file content before the file is deleted?

e.g.

```
void methodToTest() {
    File file = ...;
    // add stuff to file
    try {
        anotherMethod(file);
    } finally {
        Files.delete(Path.of(file.getPath()));
    }
}
```

I am thinking if you can run assertion codes once an argument captor captures `file` when `anotherMethod(file)` is called and before `Files.delete()` is called?

Here is the testing code as some requested:

```
myClass.methodToTest();
verify(myClass).anotherMethod(fileCaptor);
File file = fileCaptor.getValue();
// cannot check the content within the file anymore here
// even though the file object is acquired
// because the file has been deleted after calling methodToTest()
```

Comment: The fact that a file is created is an implementation detail of that method. Test the actual result of the method instead.

Comment: The result is within the file content, which I think I did the right thing by capturing it when it is passed to `anotherMethod()`. Its just that the file gets deleted BEFORE I could run any assertions.

Comment: Why don't you do your checks at the point at which you have the file? Or make a copy of it and do the checks later.

Comment: Thats the idea, but I don't know how. Right after calling `methodToTest()` the file is deleted already. There is just one line to call `methodToTest()`, and the file is created and deleted.

Comment: Why is the result in a file that you delete, instead of it being returned from your function?

Comment: Without seeing your test and the argument captor its hard to help.

Comment: @ndc85430 The file is just a temp file and not needed after `anotherMethod()` is done reading the file content, so `methodToTest()` is handling both the creation and deletion of it.

Comment: @tgdavies its just two lines, but I added it anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you call `verify(myClass)`, your class already seems to be a [`Spy`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.mockito/mockito-core/5.10.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13):

```
myClass.methodToTest();
verify(myClass).anotherMethod(fileCaptor);
File file = fileCaptor.getValue();
```

This means you can stub `anotherMethod` and have the stub capture the file.

```
doAnswer(i -> {
      final File file = i.getArgument(0);
      // read file
      // assert contents or store contents (e.g. into an `AtomicReference` outside the lambda)
    })
    .when(myClass)
    .anotherMethod(any());
myClass.methodToTest();
```

Comment: Thank you. Assertions within the `doAnswer()` worked!

Answer (score 1):

If you have to check a file, it's more like an integration test, not a unit test, even if you perform the test with a unit testing framework like JUnit.

You have to create a *spy* that stubs `anotherMethod`. Normally you would do that with Mockito like a *mock*, but in your case you will have to derive from the tested class yourself and overwrite `anotherMethod` to copy the temp file for later analysis.

Nevertheless your whole setup sounds as if `anotherMethod` should either have `private` visibility or be injected from another class, if you want to provide the method to multiple other classes. If it is `private`, you should not test it "standalone", but the whole call to `methodToTest` will have a "persisted" result (what I mean is a result that is not thrown away after the method is called).

For a clean separation of concerns you should unit test for that - and put the file access behind a layer that you can mock for tests (otherwise you cannot unit test the method but just integration test it, which makes the test slower.)

If the `methodToTest` doesn't have a "persisted" result, you actually don't need it at all.